# Yahoo finance CSV query no returning january in result

Tags: google-finance

I need to get stock prices from a web service and the only reasonable way i've found is tu use the below query string.

The problem is that with the below string the result start in February and not January. Has anybody experience with this service and can help me?

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=1&b=1&c=2010&d=1&e=1&f=2010&g=d&ignore=.csv

Also, does any body have any good advice links on financial web services. I've been on the Yahoo page but all they seem to mention is RSS feeds.

Also, the Google Finance API page is kind of confusing.

Thanks.
Conor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to the url are as follows:

```
a <- beginning month (0--11)
b <- beginning day (1--??)
c <- Beginning year
d <- End month (0--11)
e <- End day 
f <- End year
g <- 'd'=>daily, 'v'=>dividends, 'm'=>monthly,
```

So to start in January, set `a=0`, not `a=1`.

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2010&d=1&e=1&f=2010&g=d&ignore=.csv

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you have a link to any documentation for this service?

Thanks again..

Comment: @Conor: I wish I did, but no, I do not know where Yahoo publishes documentation for this. http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=1066 suggests it should be at http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/, but it beats me if it's actually there.